# Rails application running on Apache HTTPD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos

Is there a way to run Ruby on Rails app on Apache HTTPD (CentOS)?

Is this just a matter of setting up httpd.conf with VirtualHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger is probably the easiest way to get that running. Here's a [tutorial on installing Passenger on CentOS6](http://rabblemedia.net/blog/installing-rvm-ruby-rails-and-passenger-centos-6.html/), and here are [prebuilt rpms](http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/01/04/phusion-passenger-native-packages-for-redhatfedoracentos/).

Comment: Is Passenger free though? Is there any good free web server or is it ok to use HTTPD instead?

Comment: Passenger is 100% free, they have a pay version for support.

Comment: There are tons of other options if you don't want to use HTTPd (see the link in @hjc1710's answer). Passenger is the simplest if you're already using Apache, though.

Answer (score 0):

http://rubyonrails.org/deploy

Check Rails site, I think you have to use a Proxy, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by HTTPD. Seems like you want a simple Apache setup, Rails should be able to help.

EDIT: James answer looks perfect. Same as mine, but he has real CENTOS tutorials... I've never used CENTOS, just done this through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can run mod_rails aka Passenger or a Mongrel Cluster or Thin Cluster.

I find passenger the easiest, you can download it [Here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)

The Steps are quite easy

```
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Follow instructions on screen.